# Are there two triangles with equal angles and two equal sides which are not congruent?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Are there two triangles with equal angles and two equal sides which are not congruent?

I think it is impossible.

Comment: yes. not possible...

Comment: Try to look at the law of sines [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines] , and come back and say why it is impossible.

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/triangles-congruent-finding.html

Answer (score 1):

Exercise: two triangles which have two sides equal and the angles between them equal are congruent.

Comment: Hint (rather huge): If two triangles have two equal angles then *also* the third one in both is equal.

Answer (score 0):

the question is three angles of a triangle are equal and two sides are equal.
 then it must be congruent under the conditions $SAS$